# Python - How to recursively add a folder's content in a dict

Tags: python

I am building a python script which will be removing duplicates from my library as an exercise in python.  The idea is to build a dict containing a dict ( with the data and statistic on the file / folder ) for every file in folder in the library.  It currently works with a set number of subfolder.  This is an example of what it gives out.

```
>>> Files
{'/root/dupclean/working/test': {'FilenameEncoding': {'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}, 'File': False, 'T\xc3\xa9l\xc3\xa9phone': {'FilenameEncoding': {'confidence': 0.75249999999999995, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}, 'File': False, 'Extension': 'Folder', 'LastModified': 1284064857, 'FullPath': '/root/dupclean/working/test/T\xc3\xa9l\xc3\xa9phone', 'CreationTime': 1284064857, 'LastAccessed': 1284064857, 'Best Of': {'FilenameEncoding': {'confidence': 0.75249999999999995, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}, 'File': False, 'Extension': 'Folder', 'LastModified': 1284064965, 'FullPath': '/root/dupclean/working/test/T\xc3\xa9l\xc3\xa9phone/Best Of', '10 New York Avec Toi.mp3': {'FilenameEncoding': {'confidence': 0.75249999999999995, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}, 'File': True, 'Extension': 'mp3', 'LastModified': 1284064858, 'FullPath': '/root/dupclean/working/test/T\xc3\xa9l\xc3\xa9phone/Best Of/10 New York Avec Toi.mp3', 'CreationTime': 1284064858, 'LastAccessed': 1284064858, 'Size': 2314368L}, 'CreationTime': 1284064965, 'LastAccessed': 1284064857}}}}
```

This is how I am producing it now:

```
ROOT = Settings['path']
Files = {ROOT: {'File': False, 'FilenameEncoding': chardet.detect(ROOT)},}
for fileName in os.listdir ( ROOT ):
fileStats = ROOT + '/' + fileName
    if os.path.isdir ( fileStats ):
        Files[ROOT][fileName] = Analyse(fileStats)
        for fileName2 in os.listdir ( ROOT + '/' + fileName): 
            dbg(70, "Scanning " + ROOT + '/' + fileName + '/' + fileName2)
            fileStats2 = ROOT + '/' + fileName + '/' + fileName2
            #third level
            if os.path.isdir ( fileStats2 ):
                Files[ROOT][fileName][fileName2] = Analyse(fileStats2)
                for fileName3 in os.listdir ( ROOT + '/' + fileName + '/' + fileName2): 
                    dbg(70, "Scanning " + ROOT + '/' + fileName + '/' + fileName2 + '/' + fileName3)
                    fileStats3 = ROOT + '/' + fileName + '/' + fileName2 + '/' + fileName3
                    #Fourth level
                    if os.path.isdir ( fileStats3 ):
                        Files[ROOT][fileName][fileName2][fileName3] = Analyse(fileStats3)
                        for fileName4 in os.listdir ( ROOT + '/' + fileName + '/' + fileName2 + '/' + fileName3): 
                            dbg(70, "Scanning " + ROOT + '/' + fileName + '/' + fileName2 + '/' + fileName3 + '/' + fileName4)
                            fileStats4 = ROOT + '/' + fileName + '/' + fileName2 + '/' + fileName3 + '/' + fileName4
                            #Fifth level
                            if os.path.isdir ( fileStats4 ):
                                Files[ROOT][fileName][fileName2][fileName3][fileName4] = Analyse(fileStats4)
                                for fileName5 in os.listdir ( ROOT + '/' + fileName + '/' + fileName2 + '/' + fileName3 + '/' + fileName4): 
                                    dbg(70, "Scanning " + ROOT + '/' + fileName + '/' + fileName2 + '/' + fileName3 + '/' + fileName4 + '/' + fileName5)
                                    fileStats5 = ROOT + '/' + fileName + '/' + fileName2 + '/' + fileName3 + '/' + fileName4 + '/' + fileName5
                                    #Sicth level
                                    if os.path.isdir ( fileStats5 ):
                                        Files[ROOT][fileName][fileName2][fileName3][fileName4][fileName5] = Analyse(fileStats5)
                                        dbg(10, "There was still a folder left in "+ROOT + '/' + fileName + '/' + fileName2 + '/' + fileName3 + '/' + fileName4)
                                    else:
                                        Files[ROOT][fileName][fileName2][fileName3][fileName4][fileName5] = Analyse(fileStats5)
                            else:
                                Files[ROOT][fileName][fileName2][fileName3][fileName4] = Analyse(fileStats4)
                    else:
                        Files[ROOT][fileName][fileName2][fileName3] = Analyse(fileStats3)
            else:
                Files[ROOT][fileName][fileName2] = Analyse(fileStats2)
    else:
        Files[ROOT][fileName] = Analyse(fileStats)
```

This is obviously wrong, but for the life of me, I just can't figure out a way to do it recursively !
Any help or pointers would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk).

```
import os
for dirpath,dirs,files in os.walk(ROOT):
    for f in dirs + files:
        fn = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
        FILES[fn] = Analyse(fn)
```

Comment: Eyesore meet elegant solution! +1! :)

Comment: I believe this may just do what I need it to ! Thanks

Comment: mere "for f in dirs+files:" will do the job without using itertools

Comment: @Zart Updated. Could increase memory consumption though, depending on level of optimization