# Create a smart function to extract values from list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list of data like this

```py
data = [
          {
                    "name": "Box 0",
                    "type": "Box",
                    "vals": {
                              "corner1": "0,0,0",
                              "corner2": "0,0,5",
                              "rotate": "0",
                              "scale": "1",
                              "translate": "0,0,0"
                    }
          },
          {
                    "name": "Ovus 1",
                    "type": "Ovus",
                    "vals": {
                              "radiusb": "1",
                              "radiust": "0.5",
                              "rotate": "0",
                              "scale": "1",
                              "translate": "0,0,0"
                    }
          }
]
```

I would like to create a function of form

```py
fetch_attributes(name, key)
```

where I can give the key attribute values type,vals or scale.

My problem is that the scale attribute is within the vals dictionary. Can I make the function such that it gives me type when I give **key=type** and when I ask for **key=scale** it *automatically* goes inside the vals dictionary.

**My Approach**

I am using this code as example for name = 'Box 0'

```py
obj = [i for i in data if i['name'] == name][0]
key_1 = "['vals']" # If I want complete dict of vals
key_2 = "['vals']['scale']" #If I want only one val out of vals
key_3 = "['type']" # If I want type

result_1 = eval('obj' + key_1)
result_2 = eval('obj' + key_2)
result_3 = eval('obj' + key_3)
```

I would like to know if there is a better or more pythonic way of doing this task exists

**Edit**

I would like a approach which will also help or guide to create an edit_attributes function as

```py
edit_attributes(name, key, value)
```

Comment: `eval` is definitely not the best idea.  You could use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) or wrap each lookup in `try...except`.  Or you could simply say `if key == 'scale': # lookup from vals dict; else: # lookup from obj`.

Comment: there are actually many sub dictionaries other than the vals so using try except blocks will remove the flexibility in case the data inside the list changes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - How to update a multi-dimensional dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680635/python-how-to-update-a-multi-dimensional-dict)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this (now) does what you want:

```
def fetch_attributes(data, name, key):
    for dct in data:
        if dct['name'] == name:
            obj = dct
            break
    else:
        raise KeyError(f'No object with name {name!r} in data')

    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        if key in obj:
            return obj[key]

        for value in obj.values():
            if isinstance(value, dict):  # Nested dict?
                if key in value:
                    return value[key]

    raise KeyError(f'{key!r} not in data')


print(fetch_attributes(data, 'Box 0', 'vals'))   # -> {'corner1': '0,0,0', 'corner2': '0,0,5', 'rotate': '0', 'scale': '1', 'translate': '0,0,0'}
print(fetch_attributes(data, 'Box 0', 'scale'))  # -> 1
print(fetch_attributes(data, 'Box 0', 'type'))   # -> Box
```

Comment: This is a part of a tkinter UI so I can't really hardcode ['scale'] just like on the 2nd print. I can only pass key from my UI displaying type,vals,vals(translate),vals(scale) etc. I acknowledge I can just change the 2nd line ['scale'] to an argument but I am trying to use only the key argument.

Comment: I am just removing the ```if isinstance(obj,dict)``` check as it will be always true in my case.This works as expected. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This should work for any levels of dictionary nesting.

```
def find(obj, key):
  if key not in obj:
    for k in obj.keys():
      if type(obj[k]) == type({}):
        return find(obj[k], key)
  else:
    return obj[key]

  return None

def fetch_attributes(name, key):
  obj = [i for i in data if i['name'] == name][0]
  return find(obj, key)
```

However, if `obj = [i for i in data if i['name'] == name][0]` returns more than one value, then you will need a `for` loop there as well.

Comment: Where would that second loop go in your code above?

Comment: Only the ```fetch_attributes``` function will change:

```def fetch_attributes(name, key):
  search_results = []
  Result = namedtuple('Result', 'index value')

  obj_list = [i for i in data if i['name'] == name]
  for obj in obj_list:
    value = find(obj, key)
    res = Result(obj_list.index(obj), value)
    search_results.append(res)

  return search_results```

So we would need to iterate over ```obj_list``` and run ```find``` for each match. A ```namedtuple``` _Result_ holds the matching key value for each dictionary (indicated by its index in ```obj_list```).

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the second parameter of the dictionary's get() function to cascade into the sub-dictionary when the property name is not found:

```
def getProp(d,key): return d.get(key,d["vals"].get(key,None))
```

ouput:

```
for d in data:
    print([ getProp(d,"name"),getProp(d,"type"),getProp(d,"scale") ])

# ['Box 0', 'Box', '1']
# ['Ovus 1', 'Ovus', '1']
```

The assignment would be a little more convoluted but is also possible with setdefault():

```
def setProp(d,key,value):
    [d,d.setdefault("vals",dict())][key=="vals"][key] = value
```